# Blog page naming and Google indexing

Tags: blogs, google-search

I am adding a blog to my wesite, and want to maximise the articles in google searches. for example I want each page to be indexed by google and be searchable.

for example if i have 2 blog pages.
www.example.com?id=1
www.example.com?id=2

I know this is bad due to lack of keywords, so i figure this is better
www.example.com?id=my-farming-tips
www.example.com?id=cleaning-your-bath

I figure these are better as they contain the keywords, but:

Does google read the parameters?
Does google consider these to be different pages, or the same page?

cheers,

Comment: What's stopping you from using a URL rewrite rule to allow, e.g. `www.example.com/my-farming-tips`?

Comment: Thankyou so much. so simple really. This post gave me all the answers I needed. https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/.